# Links to amazon (Books) in Tags

Tags: discussion

I just got a review for a tag edit.  The person in question had added a link to a book on amazon.com. (That was all nothing more) I rejected it.

I have since done a bit of searching around.  I wasn't able to find anything official on weather or not we want books (or any paid resources linked in tags.) My opinion was that it would look like stack is recommending the book, and a book being helpful or not is very subjective.

What is our standing on this exactly?  Do we want book links in tags?

Comment: That sounds spammy.

Comment: Well, look at the [c# wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), [java wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) and [php wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) for example.  Just 3 of the top tags I looked at first.  It is a very decent alternative for the off topic book list questions.

Comment: @HansPassant looks like there is an official referrer for stackoverflow. i wouldn't mind that SE gets some payback.

Comment: Though I don't disagree @Daniel SE just got a $40m investment; I can't imagine the Amazon referer is going to have much of an impact.